# Silverlight 4 toolkit AutoCompleteBox Text property not working

Tags: silverlight, autocompletebox

I capture the KeyUp event on an AutoComplete box from the Silverlight toolkit.  If they press Escape I want to clear the value by calling autocompletebox.Text = string.Empty.  This works most of the time, but whenever I set this when the whole field is selected it does not work.  Is there another property that I should be setting instead of Text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try also assigning null to the `SelectedItem` property.

BTW Why are you using the toolkit, Silverlight 4 has an AutoCompleteBox, are you using SL3?

Comment: Yes, remember SL 4 has the AutoComplexBox because it loads as part of the SDK during install of the Toolkit.  This is not a core install though.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may encounter this problem, it turns out that while you can set the `Text` property, the best approach is to set the `SelectedItem` property.  I will submit this as a bug on Codeplex.